# Accessing BigQuery table through Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am retrieving the schema of BigQuery tables using DataFlow v1.9 using below 
code:

```
Bigquery bigQueryClient=Transport.newBigQueryClient(options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)).build();
Tables tableRequest = bigQueryClient.tables();
Table table = tableRequest.get("","","").execute();
List<TableFieldSchema> fieldss = table.getSchema().getFields();
TableSchema schemaa = table.getSchema();
```

However, the same doesn't work in Apache Beam. How to do the same in apache Beam?

I am getting below message while writing the same code in Apache beam:
"The method newBigQueryClient(options.as(BigQueryOptions.class)) is undefined for the type Transport

Thank You

Comment: Do you receive an error message? If so, please update your question to include it.

Comment: Please let me know if we can get schema with above approach in Apache beam during the execution of DataFlow job. Also, let me know if there are any other options available for this feature.

Comment: Hi PRASAD, is this a compilation error? Or an issue at runtime? Would you please post the error?

See ExampleUtils.java. Perhaps you can use this pattern to instantiate the BigQueryClient?

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/88e044fda0a7d0ea1372f075a4c7a4bd54af47da/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/ExampleUtils.java#L217